# How can I concat more than two rows of one table of mysql in jsp java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, concatenation

```
mysql> select * from keyword;
+-----+-------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+------+
| kid | productType | brand | model   | id   | ram  | var1 | var2 |
+-----+-------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+------+
|   1 | laptop      | hp    | probook | 440  | 2    |      |      |
|   2 | phone       | apple | iphone  | 5s   |      |      |      |
|   3 | desktop     | dell  | vostro  | 3250 |      |      |      |
+-----+-------------+-------+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

I want to concat "product type", "brand", "model", "id" field into one string.

I tried `"select GROUP_CONCAT(productType, brand, model, id) from keyword; "`
and got result :: `laptophpprobook440,phoneappleiphone5s,desktopdellvostro3250`.

But I want data like ::

```
"laptop hp probook 440"
```

And I want this string in my jsp page.
I tried this <%= rs.getString("productType" + "brand" + "model" + "id") %>
but this is not working.

Comment: You need `concat` or `concat_ws`

Comment: FWIW, I would do this in application code

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `concat` without `Group_` prefix:

```
select CONCAT(productType," ", brand, " ", model, " ", id) from keyword;
```

Comment: Beware that `concat` will set the result null if any of the column value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `alias` column name to get the result value. It is something like below

`select CONCAT(productType," ", brand, " ", model, " ", id) as result_val from keyword;`

And you can get value using `rs.getString("result_val");`

Comment: String sql = "select kid, CONCAT(productType," ", brand, " ", model, " ", id) as result_val from keyword";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

<table>
 <% while(rs.next()){ %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= rs.getString("kid") %></td>
   <td><%= rs.getString("result_val") %></td>
  </tr>
 <% } %>
</table>

Comment: Have you tried whether sql query return record from database?

Comment: Refer here (http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/MakeDatabaseconnection.htm) for detailed example with program

Comment: Yes I tried and I got the result in sql but not in jsp page.